# Non existent pages to error page htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm having some problems with my .htaccess file and since I don't know much of it, I was wondering if any of you could help me out. Basically what happens is the following:

Whenever I type in a non existent url, like domain.com/peanut, it shows the logged-in.php page which I have hidden in my .htaccess, which means nothing really happens and the content are being shown.

**Non existent pages needs to be redirected to ErrorDocuments. This is my .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Hide de submap pages
RewriteRule ^$ pages/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1

#hide de logged-in.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ logged-in.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/logged-in\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]


ErrorDocument 400     /400.html
ErrorDocument 401     /401.html
ErrorDocument 403     /403.html
ErrorDocument 404     /404.html
ErrorDocument 500     /500.html
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the rule that is causing it:

```
#hide de logged-in.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ logged-in.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it looks like it's something that you want. This rule essentially says "if the request is for a non-existent file or directory" rewrite it to `logged-in.php`. The rule that follows that takes requests for `logged-in.php` and redirects the browser to remove the "logged-in.php" bit of the URL.

If you want to remove it, just change your htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Hide de submap pages
RewriteRule ^$ pages/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 400     /400.html
ErrorDocument 401     /401.html
ErrorDocument 403     /403.html
ErrorDocument 404     /404.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I edited my htaccess and changed it to your code. Whenever I go to the root (sub.domain.com), it's giving me the 403 error untill I add index.php to it. Besides that, when I go to http://sub.domain.com/#dashboard (which was working perfectly fine) it also gives me the 403 error. Is there a way to still hide the /pages/ submap including the logged-in.php/ file, but also redirect users to ErrorDocuments when they fill in a non existent url?

Comment: @user3131209 not in htaccess, no. Because you're blindly routing everything that doesn't exist to logged-in.php, you have to write php code to determine if a request should return a 404 or not.